what's the purpose of SecurityContext in spring security architecture?
in spring security, SecurityContext contains an Authentication object, and we usually use SecurityContextHolder to obtain current Authentication like this
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

so why not get or set Authentication directly by SecurityContextHolderStrategy in SecurityContextHolder, what's the purpose of SecurityContext in spring security architecture?
for examply, ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy may be
final class ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy implements SecurityContextHolderStrategy {

    private static final ThreadLocal<Authentication> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

    
    @Override
    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return contextHolder.get();
    }


    @Override
    public void setAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
        contextHolder.set(authentication);

    }
    
...
}

// when obtain Authentication

SecurityContextHolder.getAuthentication();

supplement
the key point is why not use Authentication directly instead of SecurityContext, and the interface SecurityContextHolderStrategy could be used to store Authentication
public interface SecurityContextHolderStrategy {

    Authentication getAuthentication();


    void setAuthentication(Authentication authentication);

}

SecurityContextHolder
if using MODE_GLOBAL strategy, the GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy may be like this
final class GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy implements SecurityContextHolderStrategy {

    private static Authentication authenticationHolder;


    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return authenticationHolder;
    }

    public void setAuthentication(Authentication auth) {
        authenticationHolder = authentication;
    }
}


The SecurityContextHolder inherits both SecurityContext and SecurityContextHolderStrategy which means you as a user can pick what strategy you want to use.
In your provided code example you have implement one single strategy, the ThreadLocal strategy. While Springs securitycontext has multiple strategies that you can choose from depending on what type of application you are writing.
Taken from the docs:

By default, SecurityContextHolder uses a ThreadLocal to store these details, which means that the SecurityContext is always available to methods in the same thread, even if the SecurityContext is not explicitly passed around as an argument to those methods.

additionally of other strategies, again the docs:

Some applications are not entirely suitable for using a ThreadLocal, because of the specific way they work with threads. For example, a Swing client might want all threads in a Java Virtual Machine to use the same security context.


You can configure SecurityContextHolder with a strategy on startup to specify how you would like the context to be stored.


For a standalone application, you would use the
SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL strategy. Other applications might
want to have threads spawned by the secure thread also assume the same
security identity. You can achieve this by using
SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL. You can change the
mode from the default SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL in two
ways. The first is to set a system property. The second is to call a
static method on SecurityContextHolder. Most applications need not
change from the default. However, if you do, take a look at the
JavaDoc for SecurityContextHolder to learn more.

So depending on your needs you can pick what strategy you want.
That is the reason.

I draw and upload a picture, can you see that? in spring security, the interface SecurityContextHolderStrategy is used to get or set SecurityContext, no matter what implementation it is, and then we obtain Authentication object from SecurityContext, right? well, I wonder why not just get or set Authentication object directly without using SecurityContext, for example using SecurityContextHolder.getAuthentication() instead of SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(). I can't understand the design purpose of SecurityContext, which is important according to the official reference

The SecurityContect holds whomever is authenticated. The SecurityContextHolder associates a given SecurityContext with the current execution thread. In for instance reactive programming you want to extracct the SecurityContext and move it between threads. There are reasons to when you dont want the context to be associated with a thread.
